# Large scale internet application, where to start?

Tags: database-design, web-applications, security

I'm involving in kind of work that i think knowledge about large scale application, large scale web will help me much. What do you think i should take? I mean books to read, courses to take... etc...
Thanks in advance for any suggestion.

PS: maybe applications i mean are not large enough :D, kind of social network for >100k users or realtime game online for 5000 ccu. architecture and design, things to consider when you build these kind of applications

Comment: Are you talking about architecture or design?

Comment: maybe applications i mean are not large enough :D, kind of social network for >100k users or realtime game online for 5000 ccu. architecture and design, things to consider when you build these kind of applications

Answer (score 7, accepted):

security: http://www.owasp.org/index.php/Category:OWASP_Top_Ten_Project

scalability (db layer): http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596003067 (half of the book is very relevant for any database)

scalability (app layer): http://www.javaconcurrencyinpractice.com/ (half of the book is very relevant for any language with shared state and threads)

front end: [http://www.amazon.com/High-Performance-Web-Sites-Essential/dp/0596529309/](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596529309) and [http://www.amazon.com/Even-Faster-Web-Sites-Performance/dp/0596522304](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596522304)

Also, just to get a grasp of how difficult things are sometimes, you should start reading that those 2 blogs:

- http://engineering.twitter.com/
- http://www.facebook.com/notes.php?id=9445547199

Answer (score 4):

Great blog with articles and architecture overviews of big applications and websites: http://highscalability.com/

Answer (score 4):

You should read:
[What should a developer know before building a public web site?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72394/what-should-a-developer-know-before-building-a-public-web-site)