# how do web servers handle large ( millions ) of clients at the same time?

Tags: networking, webserver, scalability

Can someone explain in a high level and/or point to resources ( book / article ) that explains how the web server of websites like Wikipedia and Google handle millions of clients at the same time? Specifically, what are the resource bottle necks when dealing with clients?

Answer (score 2):

Essentially, there is not a single web server for websites like Wikipedia or Google.  There is probably a fairly large number of servers that are handling the incoming requests for these sites.  These servers will be behind a load balancer or sprayer that will actually receive the requests from the clients and distribute the workload among the servers.  Depending on the architecture of the site, there may be multiple web servers to handle the incoming requests, multiple database servers to handle the back end queries for data to drive the site, and very fast and reliable storage systems (NAS or SAN) to provide good throughput for the static content and storage for the databases.

There are some good links in the answers to [this stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3984316/large-scale-internet-application-where-to-start).  I'm guessing you got down voted because people thought you should have done some more searching before asking a general question like this.